Classification of signals from the sensor
First of all, I want to say that my knowledge of signal processing is very limited.
So I need to separate the signals into two classes. Here is a picture that shows several dozen signal observations superimposed on each other. The signals that I need to separate are shown in different colors, green and red.

At first glance, the signals are the same and cannot be separated, but if you calculate the average of all "green" signals and the average of all "red" signals, you can notice a fairly clear pattern.

Help me choose a processing method that I can use to programmatically separate these two signals

You have two problems:

identify the location
You can calculate the derivate of the signals to identify the negative fall in the signal. From these instants, you can observe the previous samples in the original signal.

decide class
From 1) the green has a higher average but you do not provide sufficient information. Possibilities:



Is the green always bigger than a given threshold? Then define threshold.
You can also define an average and std and decide based on probability


Hi! As you can see from the first picture, the "green" color is not always above the threshold, each individual signal has a lot of noise, but looking at the average of all signals, you can see that they are all different "green" and "red" (on average), but not in each individual case. It seems to me that you need to first remove the noise from each individual observation
